# can chrome apps make use of application cache?

Tags: google-chrome-app, html5-appcache, persistent-storage

In the storage section in the chrome app developer guide it reads (https://developer.chrome.com/apps/offline_storage#persistent)

"Persistent storage is storage that stays in the browser unless the user expunges it. It is available only to apps that use the File System API, **but will eventually be available to other offline APIs like IndexedDB and Application Cache.**"

there is no date for when this text is published so my question is: has EVENTUALLY happened yet or can we not yet make use of persistent storage (thus not unlimited storage) for Application Cache in chrome apps?

Comment: Why would you need AppCache in a Chrome app?

Comment: To avoid rewriting my webapp when I want to use it in a chrome kiosk

Comment: AFAIK, this is deprecated as stated in this document. The workaround would be using the service worker [Cache API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache) instead. This will make your site work offline using the service workers. Hope this helps.

Comment: Do you know if the service worker could be in the webapp or wold it have to go in the chrome app (crx) for it to be able to make use of the "unlimited storage" permission?